# Clamping TextureAddressMode in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I've been working on implementing a 2D lighting system in XNA, and I've gotten the system to work--as long as my window's dimensions are powers of two.  Otherwise, the program will fail at this line:

```
GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, Vertices, 0, 2);
```

The exception states that "XNA Framework Reach profile requires TextureAddressMode to be Clamp when using texture sizes that are not powers of two," and every attempt that I've made to slve this problem has failed--the most common solution I've found on the internet is to put the line `GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp;` directly above the line above, but that hasn't solved my problem.

I apologize if I've left out any information that could be necessary to solve this; I'll be more than happy to provide more as needed.

Comment: Are you using multiple texture stages?  If so, you'll need to be sure to reset the sampler states for each stage (that's what the [0] index is for).  If not, are you using any shaders?  Shaders can override the address mode.  Make sure they're setting it appropriately.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by texture stages (I'm pretty new to this), but I a using shaders.  I didn't write them myself, and I'm not totally sure of exactly how shaders work on a technical level--how would the shader set the address mode, and how can I best return it to the mode that I need it to be in?

Comment: You can specify the sample state inside the shader... so you should check the hlsl code...

Comment: I've never written in HLSL before; how can I specify the sampler state?

Comment: See here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509644(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you.  Now that I've defined the sampler state, how do I specify it as the active one?

Comment: Are you rendering to some sort of rendertarget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this the same question you asked before?

In your HLSL look for the line that declares the sampler that the pixel shader is using.

You can set the address mode to clamp in this line.

```
SamplerState somethingLikeThis {
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};
```

Comment: This might be in the effects.fx file or similar.