# Setting TextureAddressMode with HLSL

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, hlsl, lighting

I've been implementing a lighting system in XNA using shaders I didn't write myself, and I've run into an issue:  the system works perfectly if the dimensions of the game are powers of two (right now it's running at 1024x512), but will otherwise break down at the line `GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, Vertices, 0, 2);`, throwing an exception which states that "XNA Framework Reach profile requires TextureAddressMode to be Clamp when using texture sizes that are not powers of two."

In a search of the internet, the most common solution is to put the line `GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp` directly above the line above.  I've tried this, and it has had no effect.  In fact, during my attempts to tease out a solution, it seemed to be that `GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0]` was null before I set it with that line, leading me to believe that this problem could also perhaps be solved by selecting that as the active sampler state--although I'm also not sure how to do that.

Otherwise, based on other information I've found, I believe that I need to set the TextureAddressMode from within the shader.  I was directed to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for information on how to do so, but I confess to still being baffled--I've never used HLSL before, and I'm unsure of how to use the information on that page.

If there's any more information I need to provide, I'd be more than happy to do so, and I first asked a question which led me towards my present one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792151/clamping-textureaddressmode-in-xna).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HLSL look for the line that declares the sampler that the pixel shader is using.

You can set the address mode to clamp in this line.

```
SamplerState somethingLikeThis {
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still not completely sure how to use the sampler that I define; however, I was able to change the samplers already being used in such a way that the program now works.  Thank you.